# How to parse value from a string in php

Tags: php

I want to get the value `146273.0017` from the following string.

```
(["JPY-XAU,146273.0017"]);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So are the parentheses, brackets and semicolon part of the string ?

Comment: Yes, that is the part of string. @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex

```
$str = '(["JPY-XAU,146273.0017"]);';

preg_match("/,(.*?)\"/", $str, $res);

echo $res[1]; // 146273.0017
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// First cleanup stuff we don't need:
$string = '(["JPY-XAU,146273.0017"]);';
$string = str_replace(array('(', ')', '[', ']', '"', ';'), '', $string);

// Split the inner values
$parts  = explode(',', $string);

// Echo the results
echo $parts[0];
echo $parts[1];
```

Returns:

JPY-XAU

146273.0017

If you want you can cast that number as a float i.e.: (float)$string[1]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the numerical portion, then a regex would grab it:

```
$pattern = "/(\d*\.)?\d+/";
$subject = '(["JPY-XAU,146273.0017"]);';
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

If you're looking for whatever comes after the comma, and you're disregarding both sets of brackets around it (but they are part of the string as you clarify in the comments, so need to be ignored), then you could just split on the comma using a regex too:

```
$pattern = "/\[\((.*?),(.*?)\)\]/";
$subject = '(["JPY-XAU,146273.0017"]);';
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
}
```

Some clarification of how you're hoping to obtain the requested number would he helpful to narrow down which answer is right for you, or if neither of these (and other valid answers on this page) are the right one in your situation.

Comment: I see that while I was typing, someone else was accepted... I think considering the question, that's a good answer.